# How to Separate substrings from a certain Format of string in iOS

Tags: objective-c, regex

I am trying to find out a way to Parse a string of certain format to an Array of Substrings Ex: the Original string is

```
"hii @[jitendra pradhan](contact:3264) and @[iOSs check](contact:2514) abc xyz etc"
```

And I have to make it like

```
hii jitendra pradhan and iOSs check abc xyz etc
```

I have tried to Remove the special characters like **[,],@,(,)** through regular expression but i m not finding the exact solution which will give me the require string and the respective ids.

I  tried to group by "@[" and then to get the range of each word.

```
NSUInteger count = 0, length = [str length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length); 
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
  range = [str rangeOfString: @"@[" options:0 range:range];
  if(range.location != NSNotFound)
  {
   NSLog (@"%d"range.location);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try reading the spec for NSString.

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for your comment as i said , i  know the way how to separate the strings by character and group by a separator etc. I just trying to find a solution to parse it efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regular expressions in three steps:

Remove characters enclosed by parenthesis
Remove leading @"
Remove ]

```
NSString *string = @"hii @[jitendra pradhan](contact:3264) and @[iOSs check](contact:2514) abc xyz etc";

NSString *newString = string;
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\([^)]+\\)" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@\\["        withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\]"         withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, newString.length)];

NSLog(@"newString: %@", newString);
```

Output:

> newString: hii jitendra pradhan and iOSs check abc xyz etc